# Stack and center Bootstrap Glyphicon on top of text in list item.Stack and center Bootstrap Glyphicon on top of text in list item

Tags: html, html-lists, nav

I have a list item(s) in Bootstrap that uses a 2 span tags within an unordered list item.

I desire to center both vertically and horizontally and then stack the glyphicon above the text in list item.

In addition keep the text-decoration:none; on both active and hover states.

How do you create the css3 for this?

```
<nav>
<ul>
  <li>
   <link href="#" title="HOME">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>

<span class="glyphicon-class">about</span>

   </link>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

A span class creates an inline element. If you wish to use span class add a `<br>` after the first span class so it creates a new line.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <link href="#" title="HOME">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span><br>
        <span class="glyphicon-class">about</span>
       </link>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

Adding display: inline-block; as a style attribute will display the content horizontally. Add that to the Nav's `<li>` elements in css. I'm guessing every `<li>` may have a glyph. Add text-align:center on the `<li>`'s within the nav in css to align the `<li>`'s content in the middle.

```
nav li {
display: inline-block;
text-align:center;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

To target the Hover Action or Active you could write the css like below.

```
nav li:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}

nav li:active {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Great!! It worked. Glyphicon on top of my text link and both are centered. So with css, how do I control the amount of spacing between both the glyphicon and the linked text in my navigation? The br tag puts a large amount of space between them both.